# High memory usage in JVM level - org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.AutoConfiguredCompositeMeterRegistry

Tags: spring-boot, jvm, heap-memory, spring-cloud, spring-actuator

we had a Spring boot upgrade from 2.3.0.RELEASE to 2.5.13
spring cloud  version we are using is spring-cloud-sleuth( 2.0.0.RELEASE) and upgraded to spring-cloud-dependencies (version-2020.0.5)
After Upgrade heap memory usage is increasing heavily , from heapdump analysis seeing that below Object is accumulating in memory.
***"org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.AutoConfiguredCompositeMeterRegistry "***

If anyone faced/knows about the issue or please help me to understand what could be the possible reason for this issue.
[Eclipse analyser result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzl6b.jpg)

Please let me any other information required regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a little digging in internet i got a post which helped me to identify issue.

Avoid Spring Boot’s WebClient with uriBuilder for performing web requests.

```
  webClient .get() 
          .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/v2/products/{id}")
          .build(productId))
```

use the following for constructing a URI instead: it will avoid this memory leak.

```
 webClient .get()
       .uri("/v2/products/{id}", productId))
```

Sharing here the post for wider audience.

- https://techlab.bol.com/en/blog/avoiding-memory-leaks-with-spring-boot-webclient
- https://rieckpil.de/expose-metrics-of-spring-webclient-using-spring-boot-actuator/

Comment: this works with path variables. Any idea how to achieve passing query param/request param to URI without creating UriBuilder